# How to expand height of child based on parent parent

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="child">
      //content goeshere
    </div>
  </section>
<body>
```

This is my html code. 
I need 'child' class div's height should be based on body tag.
How can I achieve this through css.

Comment: please share your complete code example, not just posting some peace of it and hope someone will solve it for yourself

Comment: .child {
height: 100vh;
}
This is what you want ?

Comment: or this: `.container {height: 100%;} .child {height: 100%;}` Just height of body isn't  either known or defined

Comment: BTW, last tag in your snippet should be closing one: `</body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `.child` to cover whole height of screen, then you need to

1. Set body height equal 100vh - `vh` is viewport height units, 1vh = 1% of window height
2. Set `container` height to 100% of its parent, it means `body`
3. Set `child` height to 100% of its parent, it means `container`

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
} 
.child {
    height: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="child">
      //content goeshere
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Here is one more solution where height of child don't bound to container height. (backgrounds and different widths and heights added for better look)

```css
body {
     position: absolute;
     width: 80%;
     height: 80%;
     border: 1px solid green;
     background: lightgreen;
}
.container {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background: teal;
} 
.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="container">
     Before content
    <div class="child">
      //content goeshere
    </div>
    After content
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: container should not cover 100% of height and child should be based on body's height

Comment: I've added one more variant. have a look

Answer (score 0):

use same class name........

eg :

```
<body>
  <section class="child">
    <div class="child">
      //content goeshere
    </div>
  </section>
<body>
```

Comment: thats not the idea of a `child`.